# the counter is doubling

Tags: javascript, counter

While working on my personal project, I've encountered a problem. The problem is every time my function loops the counter counts twice.

JavaScript Code:

```
function punch(){

var hit;
var h1=100;

h1-=1;

counter++;

hit=setInterval('punch()',2000);
}
```

What I wanted it to do is that every 2000 milliseconds the counter goes up 1.

Comment: Don't you find in your code you try to invoke punch() by setting interval inside itself? In every 2 seconds there will be 1, 2, 4, 8,... instances of punch() running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original code every time the function punch is called is called again internally.

```
var counter = 0;

function punch(){
   var h1=100;
   h1-=1;
   counter++;
}

var hit = setInterval(punch,2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  /// call your function here
}, 2000);
```

Call your function where commented and inside the function increment your counter.

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = 0;
var h1=100;

setInterval(punch,2000);

function punch(){
    h1-=1;
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: **http://jsfiddle.net/9JLdU/3/**

```
<div id="counter"></div>
<script>
var hit;
var counter = 0;

window.punch = function()
{
    var h1=100;
    h1-=1;
    counter++;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML=counter;
}

hit = setInterval('punch()',2000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

*setInterval* will cause the function to be called about every 2 seconds until cancelled. By including another call to *setInterval* within the function, another sequence of calls is established each time it is called, so eventually you'll have thousands of instances running, each incrementing the counter.

So either use one call to *setInterval*, or have the function call itself using *setTimeout*, which only runs once. Also, it's preferred to pass a function reference to *setInterval* and *setTimeout* as passing a string calls the Function constructor and is effectively a call to *eval*, which is needlessly expensive in terms of system resources.

```
var counter = 0;

function punch() {
  // ...
  counter++;
  hit = setTimeout(punch, 2000);
}

punch();
```

or

```
var counter = 0;

function punch() {
  // ...
  counter++;
}

setInterval(punch, 2000);
```

The advantage of *setTimeout* is that you can easily vary the delay based on some other logic, or stop the sequence without cancelling the timeout.

Note that when doing:

```
hit = setInterval(...);
```

the value of *hit* is an index that can be used to cancel the interval, it is not the value returned by *punch* (which is undefined since there is no return statement).

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

The `setInterval()` method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

Read about setInerval() [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

**Syntax**

```
setInterval(function,milliseconds)
```

**Working Example** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/meatish/X7D42/)

```
<script>
    var hit = 100;
    counter = 0;
    var myVar = setInterval(function() {punch()}, 1000);

    function punch() {
        hit--;
        counter++;
    }
</script>
```